# How to make DRY code from these duplicates in C

Tags: c, sdl-2, dry

I'm trying to avoid duplicate code by writing a function that I will call.
I use SDL2 library, and call function to render pictures on the screen, it looks like this

```
SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

surface = IMG_Load("./images/star.png");
if (surface == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot find star.png \n\n");
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}
game->star = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(game->renderer, surface);
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    surface = IMG_Load("./images/clouds.png");
if (surface == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot find clouds.png \n\n");
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}
game->clouds = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(game->renderer, surface);
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    surface = IMG_Load("./images/bridge.png");
if (surface == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot find bridge.png \n\n");
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}
game->bridge = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(game->renderer, surface);
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
```

I understand that I can remake this lines of code into a function that I'll just call, I tried to make it this way

```
void loadImg(GameState* game, char fileName[]) 
{
    SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

    surface = IMG_Load(fileName);
    if (surface == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot find %s.png \n\n", fileName);
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }
    game = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(game->renderer, surface); /*I have error here*/
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}
```

and call this way, and have an error

```
loadImg(game->star, "./images/star.png");
```

```
> Exception thrown: read access violation.
game was
```

Struct of GameState

```
typedef struct
{
    Man man;
    Star stars[100];
    Ledge ledges[100];
    SDL_Texture *clouds;
    SDL_Texture *star;
    SDL_Texture *manFrames[7];
    SDL_Texture *bridge;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
} GameState;
```

Comment: you only show a small part of the exception -- what is the rest?

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
void loadImg(GameState* game, char fileName[])
```

expects a pointer to GameState as the first parameter

This

```
loadImg(game->star, "./images/star.png");
```

is passing an SDL_texture as the first parameter

so try this:

```
void loadImg(GameState *game,SDL_texture** texture, char fileName[])
```

You will need to re-write to use the texture parameter

```
void loadImg(GameState *game, SDL_texture** texture, char fileName[])
{
    SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

    surface = IMG_Load(fileName);
    if (surface == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot find %s.png \n\n", fileName);
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }
    *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(game->renderer, surface); 
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}
```

Then your call would be

```
loadImg(game, &game->star, "./images/star.png");
```

> Note: you get this error because when you de-reference a texture as a pointer to a GameState struct you reference a random location in memory (which you don't have rights to access)